# Dialogflow messenger and webdemo is not displaying a response text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created an event trigger to detect Intent using an API and dispay a text message from default responses. My event is trigerring the Intent and displaying the response text perfectly in my Terminal and I am able to see the fulfilment text showing the same response text in my dialogflow console history and Raw Interaction Log as well. Why am I not receiving the same in dialogflow messenger and webdemo,? I am receiving other messages correctly.